# What's the meaning of `?:` in regular expression

Tags: regex

I saw a regular expression to match a URL: `/^\/users?(?:\/(\d+)(?:\.\.(\d+))?)?/`. I am confused by the usage of `?:` in the beginning of each group match.

What's the meaning of that?

Comment: What regex library are you using?

Comment: svick: Does it really matter?  Clearly a Perl-compatible one.  (This syntax was introduced in Perl 5.)

Comment: @svick: It's a very widely adopted extension to the POSIX spec.

Comment: Well, there could be some small details that are implementation-specific. And it would also affect which documentation link is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`(?:)` (the `()` are part of the expression) is a *non-capturing group*.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html.

Answer (score 5):

It's a non-capturing group, so if a match is made that particular group will not be captured.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Answer (score 1):

Read through: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

> (?:...)

A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.